# What dataLength to use for getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption() for a SOL account?

Tags: web3.js, account, rent

According to [the Solana documentation](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption) the minimum balance/amount to be send to new SOL account can be calculated using `getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption()`

`getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption()` takes a `dataLength` parameter. What should `dataLength` be for a new account?

---

There is [an ACCOUNT_SIZE constant for SPL token](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/variables/ACCOUNT_SIZE.html) but my question is or a native SOL account without additional tokens.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just a system account that stores no data, you can simply create it with 0 length.